# Validating Array Elements in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have an array,

```
$dataArray =

    [
        0 => [
          "member_email" => 4849092427.0
          "first_name" => "Tom"
        ]

        1 => [
          "member_email" => 4849092427.0
          "first_name" => "Clement"
        ]
    ]
```

and a validator,

```
$validator = Validator::make($dataArray, [
                "*.member_number" => "date",
                "*.first_name" => "email",
            ]);
```

I have set the validator to fail but it's not failing. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make sure your syntax is valid; you're missing `,`s after your `member_email` values in the array, and between array elements.

Comment: Also, how are you using the validator? When I use `$validator->passes()`, I get `false`, as expected, as `Tom` and `Clement` are not valid email addresses. Changing those values to `Tom@test.com`, and `Clement@test.com` causes `$validator->passes()` to be `true`.

Comment: Your $dataArray contains the key "member_email" and your validator is configured at "member_number"